# How to localize DataAnnotation in MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 in my Model I need to localize DataAnnotation, using the following code

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = Resources.Account_Login_UserName)]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I receive this error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Display(Name = "Account_Login_UserName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have a similar related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699594/how-localize-errormessage-in-dataannotation   could you help? thanks