# How localize ErrorMessage in DataAnnotation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC 5 I need to localize an ErrorMessage for a DataAnnotation attributes.
I receive the following error

ERROR

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

In model

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = Resources.Account_Register_ConfirmPasswordErrorMessage)]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use [`ErrorMessageResourceName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcename) and [`ErrorMessageResourceType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcetype) properties.

For example like this:

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ConfirmPasswordErrorMessage",
  ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(<<type_of_your_resoruce_class>>)]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Uros

Comment: This may work, but according to the ASP.NET CORE documentation here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html#dataannotations-localization, we should be able to localize these DataAnnotation error messages without specifying resource name and type. Whatever I try, however, I do not mange to get this working. Can someone share some experience on that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything, just create your resource file in right place.

For example *Resources* > *ViewModels* > *LoginVm.ka-GE.resx* (Georgian culture-info)

in LoginVm:
`[Required(ErrorMessage = "UserName is Required")]`

and in *LoginVm.ka-GE.resx* just add

`UserName is Required` > `სახელი არის აუცილებელი` < (it's Georgian Language)

and all done.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-1.0#dataannotations-localization)'s a detailed explanation on how to do this:

You add appropriate culture resx files to conventional folders, and tell the DA engine to look through them:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
            options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
        });
}
```

So for this model:

```cs
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is not a valid email address.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

You'd add a resx file in one of the following locations:

- *Resources/ViewModels.Account.RegisterViewModel.fr.resx*
- *Resources/ViewModels/Account/RegisterViewModel.fr.resx*

For non-ASP.NET environments such as WPF, WinForms or others, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59343684/75500) answer.

Comment: You've mixed two things together. SharedResource registered in ConfigureServices works if you want to use one file across classe. Resources/ViewModels.Account.RegisterViewModel.fr.resx will work in case you want to have a separated translation for each class (ie. you can translate the same string differently in different models).